# Stop bash script without command line

Tags: bash, shell, bamboo

I've got a problem, which I cannot solve on my own.

I want to start a bash script on bamboo, so I cannot stop it with `^C`. This bash script starts a server, which should run after stopping the script.

If I start the script with the command line, it works as it should, but in order to stop the script I either have to enter `Enter` or `^C` to exit the script. But I cannot do this in Bamboo!

This is a short version of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
./Server &
```

I start it with: `/bin/bash ./executeServer.sh &`

At the end of the script I tried to write:

`exit 0` -> no consequence

`kill %1` -> the script stops before starting the server

`^C` -> unknown command

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I enter `nohup ./executeServer.sh` it works!

Also see:
[exiting shell script with background processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122780/exiting-shell-script-with-background-processes)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a little bit overcomplicated. Actually you do not need to start `bash` as it is started when You start `./executeServer.sh`. Add executable rights to `./executeServer.sh` and start it as it is. And do not need to start it in the background, as it already starts `Server` in the background in the script.

Comment: Thanks for this hint! This works fine, but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @IsaMunich: Sorry, which script you are talking about? I assume it is the `./executeServer.sh`. It stops automatically, after starting `./Server`. You do not need to stop! So if it is not stopping, then the problem is not in this snipplet.

Comment: But why doesn't Bamboo stop? I have to quit this task on my own and then there is "Build was not successfull" but it executes my script as it should... If I start it via the command line, I also have to enter `Enter` to be able to enter a new command.

Comment: @IsaMunich: Ok. What happen if You just start an empty `bash` script (only having the `#!/bin/bash` line from your script)? Is it stopping properly?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. But now I got a hint from a friend of mine: If I enter `nohup ./executeServer.sh` it works! Thank you!!! (Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122780/exiting-shell-script-with-background-processes)

Comment: @IsaMunich: `nohup` just redirects `stdin` to `/dev/null`, `stdout` to `nohup.out` and `stderr` to `stdin` (so to the `nohup.out` file). Maybe the `stdin` caused the problem in your case.